# Find and copy tables with 1 row

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a Word document with multiple tables and I want to copy and put into a new document only those tables with 1 row. I have VBA code to copy all tables from the source doc to the new doc, but want to only copy those tables with 1 row. Here's the code I have so far (credit: WordTips, The Macros ed 9)

```
Sub CopyTables()
  Dim Source As Document
  Dim Target As Document
  Dim tbl As Table
  Dim tr As Range
Set Source = ActiveDocument
Set Target = Documents.Add

For Each tbl In Source.Tables
Set tr = Target.Range
tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
tr.FormattedText = tbl.Range.FormattedText
tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
tr.Text = vbCrLf
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Count` property of the `tbl` to find out how many `Rows` you have.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyTables()
    Dim Source As Document
    Dim Target As Document
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim tr As Range
    Set Source = ActiveDocument
    Set Target = Documents.Add

    For Each tbl In Source.Tables
        If tbl.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Set tr = Target.Range
            tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            tr.FormattedText = tbl.Range.FormattedText
            tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            tr.Text = vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If your tables have a row of headings and a row of data, then use `tbl.Rows.Count > 2` instead of 1. For more info see Table.Rows property (Word), https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.rows